# bad operand types for binary operator ' ' first type string second type string

Tags: java

What is this error for?
bad operand types for binary operator ' ' first type string second type string

```
 if (pers.gender=="Male"||pers.gender=="male"||pers.gender ="MALE")
            {
                System.out.print("What is his last name? ");
                Person.lastName=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("What is his age? ");
                Person.age=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("What is his job? ");
```

}

Comment: Use equals() to compare strings. In your case I would use ``"male".equalsIgnoreCase(pers.gender)``

Comment: And the way @NomadMaker wrote it is a much **safer** way of doing the `.equals` because what if `pers.gender` isn't set.

Comment: The 3rd clause in the 'if' uses an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator (as well as the previously-mentioned problems)